# How to convert relative url to absolute url in c

Tags: c, url, uri

I am building a web crawler. I can download pages and using gumbo I can extract `href` from the web pages. But many of the urls extracted are relative urls. How can I convert relative urls to absolute urls using C.

The following is some code using gumbo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <gumbo.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include "http_parser.h"

#define MAX_HEADER_BYTES 8192

static void search_for_links(GumboNode* node) {
    if (node->type != GUMBO_NODE_ELEMENT) {
        return;
    }
    GumboAttribute* href;
    if (node->v.element.tag == GUMBO_TAG_A &&
    (href = gumbo_get_attribute(&node->v.element.attributes, "href"))) {
        printf("Got url %s\n", href->value);
    }

    GumboVector* children = &node->v.element.children;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < children->length; ++i) {
        search_for_links((GumboNode *)children->data[i]);
    }
}

static const char* find_title(const GumboNode* root) {
    assert(root->type == GUMBO_NODE_ELEMENT);
    assert(root->v.element.children.length >= 2);

    //printf("find_title() called\n");
    const GumboVector* root_children = &root->v.element.children;
    GumboNode* head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < root_children->length; ++i) {
        GumboNode* child = root_children->data[i];
        if (child->type == GUMBO_NODE_ELEMENT &&
        child->v.element.tag == GUMBO_TAG_HEAD) {
            head = child;
            //printf("HEAD tag found\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    assert(head != NULL);

    GumboVector* head_children = &head->v.element.children;
    for (int i = 0; i < head_children->length; ++i) {
        //printf("In loop iteration %d\n", i);
        GumboNode* child = head_children->data[i];
        if (child->type == GUMBO_NODE_ELEMENT &&
        child->v.element.tag == GUMBO_TAG_TITLE) {
            //printf("TITLE tag found\n");
            if (child->v.element.children.length != 1) {
                return "<empty title>";
            }
            GumboNode* title_text = child->v.element.children.data[0];
            assert(title_text->type == GUMBO_NODE_TEXT || title_text->type == GUMBO_NODE_WHITESPACE);
            return title_text->v.text.text;
        }
    }
    return "<no title found>";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    int bytes;
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());

    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while (read = getline(&line, &len, fp) != EOF){

        if (line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n')
            line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
        char buffer[MAX_HEADER_BYTES];
        char head_buffer[1024], get_buffer[1024];
        char *header_token, *line_token, location_line[1024], result_line[1024], content_type_line[1024], content_length_line[1024];
        char *cmp = "\r\n";
        char location[1024], content_type[1024];
        int content_length, return_code;
        struct http_parser_url u;
        char        schema[1024];
        char        host[1024];
        char        path[8192];
        location_line[0] = '\0';
        result_line[0] = '\0';
        content_type_line[0] = '\0';
        content_length_line[0] = '\0';
        portno = 80;

        memset(schema, 0, sizeof(schema));
        memset(host, 0, sizeof(host));
        memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));

        if (http_parser_parse_url(line, strlen(line), 0, &u) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "http_parser_parse_url() failed\n");
            continue;
        } else {
            if ((u.field_set & (1 << UF_HOST))) {
                strncpy(host, line + u.field_data[UF_HOST].off, u.field_data[UF_HOST].len);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "No host name in line %s\n", line);
                continue;
            }
            if ((u.field_set & (1 << UF_SCHEMA))) {
                strncpy(schema, line + u.field_data[UF_SCHEMA].off, u.field_data[UF_SCHEMA].len);
            } else {
                strcpy(schema, "http");
            }
            if ((u.field_set & (1 << UF_PATH))) {
                strcpy(path, line + u.field_data[UF_PATH].off);
            } else {
                strcpy(path, "/");
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(schema, "https")) {
            printf("http detected. Using port no 80\n");
            portno = 80;
        } else {
            printf("https detected. Using port no 443\n");
            portno = 443;
        }


        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) {
            perror("ERROR opening socket");
            exit(0);
        }

        //printf ("Resolving %s\n", line);
        server = gethostbyname(host);
        if (server == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host as %s\n", host);
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }
        //printf("%s\n",line);

        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

        //printf("Connecting to %s\n", line);
        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
            perror("ERROR connecting");
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        //printf("Sending HEAD request to %s\n", line);
        sprintf(head_buffer, "HEAD %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", path, host);

        size_t recived_len = 0;
        if (portno == 80){
            ssize_t nByte = send(sockfd, head_buffer, strlen(head_buffer), 0);
            if (nByte <= 0) {
                perror("send");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            //printf("%s", head_buffer);

            //printf("Receiving response from %s\n", line);         
            if ((recived_len = recv(sockfd, buffer, MAX_HEADER_BYTES-1, 0)) > 0) {
                //bzero(buffer, 256);
                //printf("%s", buffer);
            }
        } else if (portno == 443) {
            ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
            SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
            if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == 0 )
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            else
            {
                printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
                SSL_write(ssl, head_buffer, strlen(head_buffer));
                bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                buffer[bytes] = 0;
                printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buffer);
            }
        }

        //printf("Parsing headers from %s\n", line);
        header_token = strtok(buffer, cmp);

        while (header_token != NULL)
        {
            //printf ("header_token: %s\n\n", header_token);
            if (strncmp(header_token, "Content-Length:", strlen("Content-Length:")) == 0 
            || strncmp(header_token, "content-length:", strlen("content-length:")) == 0)
            {
                //printf ("header_token %s is equal to Content-Length:\n", header_token);
                strcpy(content_length_line, header_token);
            }
            else if (strncmp(header_token, "Location:", strlen("Location:")) == 0
                || strncmp(header_token, "location:", strlen("location:")) == 0)
            {
                //printf ("header_token %s is equal to Location:\n", header_token);
                strcpy(location_line, header_token);
            } else if (strncmp(header_token, "Content-Type:", strlen("Content-Type:")) == 0
                || strncmp(header_token, "content-type:", strlen("content-type:")) == 0)
            {
                //printf ("header_token %s is equal to Content-Type:\n", header_token);
                strcpy(content_type_line, header_token);
            } else if (strncmp(header_token, "HTTP/1.1", strlen("HTTP/1.1")) == 0)
            {

                //printf ("header_token %s is equal to HTTP/1.1\n", header_token);
                strcpy(result_line, header_token);

            } 
            header_token = strtok(NULL, cmp);
        }

        if (strlen(content_length_line) > 0) 
        {
            line_token = strtok(content_length_line, " ");
            line_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            content_length = atoi(line_token);
            //printf ("Content-Length = %d\n", content_length);
        }
        if (strlen(content_type_line) > 0)
        {
            char *ret;
            ret = strstr(content_type_line, ";");
            if (ret)
            {
                line_token = strtok(content_type_line, ";");
                line_token = strtok(content_type_line, " ");
                line_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(content_type, line_token);
                //printf ("Content_Type = %s\n", content_type);
            }
            else 
            {
                line_token = strtok(content_type_line, " "); 
                line_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                strcpy(content_type, line_token);
                //printf ("Content_Type = %s\n", content_type);
            }
        }
        if (strlen(location_line) > 0)
        {
            line_token = strtok(location_line, " ");
            line_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(location, line_token);
            //printf ("Location = %s\n", location);
        }
        if (strlen(result_line) > 0)
        {
            line_token = strtok(result_line, " ");
            line_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            return_code = atoi(line_token);
            //printf ("Return code = %d\n", return_code);
        }

        if (recived_len == -1) {
            perror("recv");
        }


        if (return_code == 200 && strcmp(content_type, "text/html") == 0 && content_length > 0)
        {
            //char buffer[2048];            
            //char get[content_length + MAX_HEADER_BYTES];
            char *get = malloc((content_length + MAX_HEADER_BYTES)*sizeof(char));
            if (get == NULL) {
                fprintf(stdout, "Out of memory\n");
                return (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            char *html;
            printf ("Return code = %d\n", return_code);
            printf ("Content-Length = %d\n", content_length);
            printf("Sending GET request to %s\n", line);
            sprintf(get_buffer, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", path, host);
            size_t i = 0;           
            if (portno == 80){
                ssize_t nByte = send(sockfd, get_buffer, strlen(get_buffer), 0);
                if (nByte <= 0) {
                    perror("send");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                printf("%s", get_buffer);

                printf("Receiving response from %s\n", line);
                size_t recived_len = 0;
                while ((recived_len = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0)) > 0) {
                    //bzero(buffer, 256);
                    if (recived_len == -1) {
                        break;
                    } else {                
                        printf("Received %zu bytes\n",recived_len);
                        memcpy(get+i, buffer, recived_len);
                        i += recived_len;
                    }
                }
                if (recived_len == -1) {
                    perror("recv");
                    close(sockfd);
                    continue;
                }
                get[i] = '\0';
            } else if (portno == 443){
                SSL_write(ssl, get_buffer, strlen(get_buffer));
                do
                {
                    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    printf("Received %d bytes\n",bytes);
                    printf("Received total of %ld bytes of %d\n", i+bytes, content_length);
                    //printf("Buffer contents: %s\n", buffer);
                    memcpy(get+i, buffer, bytes);
                    i += bytes;
                } while (bytes > 0);
                SSL_free(ssl);
            }           

            printf("%s\n", get);

            html = strstr(get, "\r\n\r\n");
            if (html != NULL)
            {
                html[0] = '\0';
                printf("\n\nHTML\n\n%s\n\n", html+strlen("\r\n\r\n"));

                GumboOutput *output;
                GumboAttribute *href;
                href = NULL;

                output = gumbo_parse(html+strlen("\r\n\r\n"));
                if (output == NULL) 
                {
                    printf ("gumbo_parse() failed with %s", line);
                }
                const char* title = find_title(output->root);
                printf("%s\n", title);

                search_for_links(output->root);

                gumbo_destroy_output(&kGumboDefaultOptions, output);
                free(get);
            } else {
                free(get);
                close(sockfd);
                continue;
            }
        }
        content_length = 0;
        close(sockfd);
    }
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code requires a file with one url per line.

I would prefer to be able to do this with a few lines of C code but I could live with using some library if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `libwget` library you can convert relative to absolute URIs as follows:

```
#include <wget.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    wget_iri *base = wget_iri_parse("http://example.com/subdir/y.html?e=2", NULL);
    wget_buffer *buf = wget_buffer_alloc(128);

    const char *relative_url = "../x.png";
    printf("%s\n", wget_iri_relative_to_abs(base, relative_url, strlen(relative_url), buf));

    wget_buffer_free(&buf);
    wget_iri_free(&base);
}
```